# What is the difference between these two types of exponential in Python

Tags: python, math, exponential

Please explain to me the difference between them?

```
import math

print math.exp(2)

print

print 2 ** 3
```

============================

```
7.38905609893

8
```

Answer (score 3):

You are squaring e with `math.exp(2)`, e is 2.71828183, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)

With `2 ** 3`, you are raising 2 to the third power.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing `math.exp()` with `math.pow()`: `math.pow(2, 3) == float(2**3)`.

Answer (score 1):

`math.exp(2)` is `e` raised to the second power, `2 ** 3` is 2 raised to the 3rd power.